# Add colour to plot in R

Tags: r, graphics, colors, plot

I am working in `R` with the package `smacof`.

I have a [image: graph] on which I would like to see the points 1 to 10 in Red, and the others leave black.

I made it with the following commands:

```
nations_indscal2<-smacofIndDiff(nations_list, ndim=2, metric=FALSE, 
                               constraint="indscal",itmax=10000)

nations_indscal2$gspace
plot(nations_indscal2)

nations_indscal2$cweights
weightspace(nations_indscal2,20,1,2)
```

I tried (for point 1):

```
text(nations_indscal2$cweights[[1]], col="red")
weightspace(nations_indscal2,20,1,2)
```

I get no error, but it doesn't work either. Any ideas where I am wrong?

Please find a reproducible example of the `nations_list` here:

```
list(structure(c(6, 1, 6, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 5, 8, 6, 5, 8, 8, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6, 1, 8, 
5, 3, 7, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", "Cuba", 
"Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", "USA"
), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
    upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 1, 6, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 3, 5, 8, 6, 5, 8, 8, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6, 
    1, 8, 5, 3, 7, 4, 7, 1, 2, 3, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 
    2, 6, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 6), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(7, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 
    5, 7, 7, 4, 7, 6, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(7, 5, 7, 5, 3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 8, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 6, 
    1, 6, 4, 2, 5, 7, 6, 7, 1, 5, 5), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(7, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 
    5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 6, 3, 6, 4, 6, 7, 5, 4, 6, 
    6, 7, 1, 5, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 
    1, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 8, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 7, 
    4, 8, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6), Labels = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, 
        diag = TRUE, upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(5, 3, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 6, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, 7, 
    3, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 7, 1, 6, 6), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(4, 2, 2, 6, 6, 3, 8, 7, 6, 1, 2, 8, 4, 2, 8, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 4, 8, 7, 1, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    2, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 7, 8, 2, 3, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 4, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    2, 7, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3, 7, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 2, 5, 6, 8, 3, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 8, 2, 7, 1), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 6, 7, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 5, 8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 5, 8, 
    2, 8, 7, 7, 8, 5, 8, 2, 7, 3, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 2, 7, 4, 4, 6, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 6, 7, 5, 7, 7, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 7, 7, 
    6, 7, 2, 6, 4, 6, 7, 2, 7, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 7, 
    3, 6, 7, 3, 7, 3, 6, 2, 6, 2, 6), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 6, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 7, 6, 8, 6, 6, 7, 
    7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 8, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 
    2, 6, 7, 6, 8, 7, 7, 8, 1, 8, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(8, 7, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 8, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 8, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 6, 5, 8, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(6, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7, 5, 
    5, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 6, 3, 7, 
    2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 4, 7, 3, 6, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 7, 5, 6, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 7, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
    3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 5, 7, 7, 0, 6, 7), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(7, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 6, 
    5, 7, 4, 8, 6, 8, 6, 4, 8, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2, 4, 7, 
    1, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 0, 2, 5, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE), 
    structure(c(4, 1, 2, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1, 8, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    2, 1, 1, 0, 6, 2, 0, 7, 1, 8, 8), Labels = c("Brazil", "Congo", 
    "Cuba", "Egypt", "France", "India", "Israel", "Japan", "China", 
    "USA"), Size = 10L, call = as.dist.default(m = data, diag = TRUE, 
        upper = FALSE), class = "dist", Diag = TRUE, Upper = FALSE))
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean.  Most likely it's because (see `?text`) you forgot to specify x,y locations as well as the text strings  to plot.

Comment: Sorry but your structure it is not reproducible.   could not find function  `as.dist.default` and then what is `weightspace`?

Comment: Do you have: `install.packages("smacof")
library(smacof)`? `weightspace` is the amount of weight each individual attaches to each dimension.

Comment: @kwanti yes otherwise I can't produce my answer. weightspace is in this package? I can't find it.

Comment: Right, sorry, had to make the function: `weightspace<-function(indscaloutput,nindividuals,xdim=1,ydim=2){
  weights<-array(NA,c(nindividuals,indscaloutput$ndim))
  for (i in 1:nindividuals){ weights[i,]<-diag(indscaloutput$cweights[[i]]) }
  plot(weights[,xdim],weights[,ydim],"n")
  text(weights[,xdim],weights[,ydim],seq(1,nindividuals),cex=1) 
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrite your weightspace function:

```
nindividuals <- 15
weights <- sapply(nations_indscal2$cweights[1:nindividuals],diag)
plot(x=weights[1,],y = weights[2,],type ='n')
text(x=weights[1,],y = weights[2,],
     labels = seq(1,nindividuals),cex=1,col = c(rep('red',10),rep(1,6)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but note that you coloured the objects (10 nations in my case) in the Group Object Space, while I want to colour replications (individuals) in the Weight Space.

Comment: oops..you mean the plot generated by your weightspace function? really I can't understand without a reproducible example.